# LINQ .SUM() and nullable db values

Tags: c#, linq

I know why this is happening but can somebody point me in the right direction of syntax?

Currently I have:

```
var expense = from e in db.I_ITEM
              where e.ExpenseId == expenseId
              select e;

return expense.Sum(x => x.Mileage ?? 0);
```

My problem is that x.Mileage is of type "double?" and has null values in the db.

The error I get is:

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The cast to value type 'Double' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.
```

What would be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm surprised that fails, but an alternative which *might* work is simply to sum the nullable values and *then* use the null coalescing operator:

```
return expense.Sum(x => x.Mileage) ?? 0d;
```

Certainly in LINQ to Objects this would do the right thing, ignoring null values and giving you a null result (before the null coalescing operator) if there were no non-null values in the sequence.

Comment: Isn't this really a bug in Linq to whatever? Type safety is broken.

Comment: @sinelaw: It looks like it, yes. It's hard to say without more details though.

Answer (score 5):

What about excluding the nulls, ie

```
var expense = 
          from e in db.I_ITEM
          where (e.ExpenseId == expenseId) && (e.Mileage.HasValue)
          select e;

 return expense.Sum(x => x.Mileage);
```

Answer (score 1):

may give you an opinion...

```
    decimal depts = 0;

    var query = from p in dc.Payments
                where p.UserID == UserID
                select p.Amount;

    if (query.Count() > 0)
    {
        depts = query.Sum();
    }

    return depts;
```

Comment: Is the `if (query.Count() > 0)` needed?

Answer (score 0):

Which O/R mapper are you using, and which DB are you using? (Linq to SQL/Entity Framework/SQL Server)?

Since the expression is executed in the DB as a SQL statement, I would think it would work without the coalescing operator:

var expense = from e in db.I_ITEM
              where e.ExpenseId == expenseId
              select e;

return expense.Sum(x => x.Mileage);

Answer (score 0):

```
var expense = (from e in db.I_ITEM
              where e.ExpenseId == expenseId
              select e.Mileage??0D);
return expense.Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Nullable Field:**
If the calculating **field is nullable** then no need to do anything special. Just use **sum** as it is, like below:

```
var summation = expense.Sum(x => x.Mileage);
```

Here, the summation is nullable (double?). If you make it not nullable then use the ***null coalescing operator*** and set a default value 0(zero), like below:

```
var summation = expense.Sum(x => x.Mileage) ?? 0d;
```

---

**Not Nullable Field:**
But, if the calculating **field is not nullable**, then you need to cast nullable first for summation, like this below:

```
var summation = expense.Sum(x => (double?)x.Mileage);
```

Also here, the summation is nullable (double?). If you make it not nullable then use the ***null coalescing operator***, like below:

```
var summation = expense.Sum(x => (double?)x.Mileage)?? 0d;
```